# Why do I have multiple python executables?

Tags: python, path

I am trying to add python to my PATH variable, but I'm not sure which one to add, or what the difference is.

I have one in `\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe`
and also one in `c:\windows\py.exe`

I understand that Python is supposed to be put into your PATH file when you install it, but when I tried to use `python` in command prompt it told me there was no such command. I checked the path file and sure enough there was no mention of python. So to quickly navigate to the location of python I right clicked on it's entry in the start menu and told it to open file location. The first time it took me to /python35-32, the second time it took me to /windows...

Looks like [python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEhg.png) was added 6 seconds prior to [py.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XraK.png). They both do the same thing though.

So I mean seriously... Why exactly does py.exe exist? Can I do with out it?

Comment: You understand that Python already exists in your PATH variable since C:windows exists in it more then likely?  You tell us Python isn't a default file, it something you added, so compare the properties of both files to determine if they are the same or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one in your `%WinDir%` is a launcher.

It's not a functional Python executable but rather a `exe` version of shortcut. With that file exists in `%WinDir%` you can type `py` or `py.exe` anywhere in a command prompt to call Python. This special shortcut doesn't require modifying `%Path%`, and it is a separate checkbox when installing Python.

The one in your installation folder (`python.exe`) is the actual Python executable. If the installation folder isn't in your `%Path%` then you can't use `python.exe` in command prompt. You can either add the installation folder to `%Path%` or use `py.exe` instead as mentioned above.